# ¿Cómo desordenar filas de un CSV usando random.shuffle?

Tags: python, csv, numpy

#### Descripción de problema:

Tengo un archivo CSV el cual es una tabla de 2 columnas y 301 filas, en el archivo se encuentran ordenadas sus 301 filas, lo que quiero lograr es ordenar aleatoriamente estas filas, para ello creí buena idea emplear el método `random.shuffle` de Numpy.

#### Código realizado:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

tabla = pd.read_csv('/content/tabla.csv')
np.random.shuffle(tabla)
```

#### Error obtenido:

`KeyError: Traceback (most recent call last)`

#### Información adicional:

1. Revisando la documentación de Numpy se menciona que `random.shuffle` solo se puede aplicar a listas mutables, lo cual me llevó a preguntarme que tipo de dato es mi tabla con `type(tabla)` lo cual me resultó en `pandas.core.frame.DataFrame` Sin embargo hasta donde he investigado un DataFrame es mutable.
2. No existe problema alguno relacionado con la carga del archivo CSV, pues lo puedo visualizar en el cuaderno de Júpiter al escribir el nombre del archivo `tabla`

Comment: si el DataFrame es mutable, la pregunta sería, ¿es una lista?, porque supongo que debe cumplir con el apellido pero también con el nombre. ¿Has intentado leer el archivo csv directamente (sin pandas)?

Comment: @jachguate Tienes toda la razón, el DataFrame no se considera una lista por eso se rompía el código cuando intentaba aplicar el método `random.shuffle` para ello primero debía de haber convertido el DataFrame a una lista usando `.to_numpy()` y después `random.shuffle`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Una solución:

```
import csv
import random

with open("doscol.csv") as csv_file:
    data_reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
    lista = sorted(data_reader, key = lambda x: random.randint(0, 1000))
    print(lista)
```

Usamos `sorted` para "ordenar" un iterable, en este caso, `data_reader`, que devuelve las líneas del archivo como listas de valores.

La clave está en usar `sorted` especificando una llave (parámetro `key=`) que genera un entero aleatorio. De esa manera, el orden no guarda relación con la información del .csv.

**Demo**

*doscol.csv*

```
uno, dos
1, 10
2, 11
3, 12
4, 13
5, 14
6, 15
7, 16
8, 17
9, 18
10,19
```

produce un resultado variable, del tipo:

```
[['10', '19'], ['4', ' 13'], ['3', ' 12'], ['6', ' 15'], ['5', ' 14'], ['8', ' 17'], ['uno', ' dos'], ['7', ' 16'], ['2', ' 11'], ['1', ' 10'], ['9', ' 18']]
```

Nota: La demo incluye la primera línea de cabecera, la que se puede descartar previamente de ser necesario.

Answer (score 1):

Después de un tiempo encontré una solución usando `random.shuffle` Y es como sigue:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

tabla = pd.read_csv('/content/tabla.csv')
tabla= tabla.to_numpy()
np.random.shuffle(tabla)
```